# Java EE way of ensuring init of all EAR-parts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am wondering how it would be possible to ensure a init of a complete application without having the problem that some application components may be accessed or fired.

I am talking about Java EE 6/Java EE 7 applications, which contain multiple WAR and EJB components.
The EAR-application containts Message driven beans (fired without control by external accesses), Servlets (fired/accessed without control by users or interface systems), and TimerEJBs, which itself get triggered by a defined schedule.

Imagine, you have to ensure on startup of the EAR application that application parts have to be initialized. E.g. you run tools like database migrations, which may take hours.
How is it possible in Java EE 6/Java EE 7 to control that no of the above mentioned parts of the application may even get executed until the init has properly passed the initialization.
And if the initialization fails, to reject operations on any of the services in Java EE?

I hope I could explain my issue in the correct manner. For short: how can I execute "Init"-code before any other code of my application is executed? And how can I avoid execution of any other code if my "Init"-code fails?
Is there a standard Java EE 6/Java EE 7 way? If not, is there a jboss7/wildfly way?

Comment: Shekhar, thank you for you hint, but maybe you have forgot this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition
I could rename it properly to JavaEE, but I hope you will forgive me ;-)

Comment: @shekharsuman: J2EE is older, the new one is JEE.

Comment: Oh,SORRY,I am too late to comment.SORRY @hkais.

Answer (score 3):

here's how we did it:

for every application/service (ear or war, take your pick), have a "startupFinished" @Startup @Singleton.
this singleton will depend on all other singletons within that application - those would be that singletons that do all the actual init work (and to avoid pitfalls with lazy-initialization of reference its best to call some isInitialized() method on all of them).

all MDBs within an application depend on that application's StartupFinished singleton (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142246/suspend-mdb-message-processing-until-startupbean-has-finished-initialization) for how).

for dependencies across applications (cross ears) - if A.ear depends on B.ear have A's StartupFinished singleton inject B's StartupFinished (you will need to expose it as a @Remote EJB).

even better, to do this properly you will need a StartupStarted singleton in A that depends on B's StartupFinished one - to really make sure that B is entirely and completely up before A starts initialization.

Comment: Radai, did not know the @Startup Annotation. Very interessting. We choosed AOP to ensure, even if a developer forgets to implement stuff, AOP will not forget it. So no unitialized access to the business code is possible. Radai, I am thinking if you define a generic EJB superclass and inject your StartupEJB in the superclass. Would this injection work also in your manner? Now you only have to ensure, that your developers get checks with PMD or checkstyle to use a specific superclass with the StartupEJB injection.
Have not tested it, but is this superclass "workaround" possible?

Comment: @cilap - a common superclass would work, yes, but the important thing is to place this on all "entry points" into your code. EJBs are usually not a entry point - unless you expose @ Remote EJBs or use @ Scheduled methods on them. jax-rs/ws resources and MDBs tend to be the classic entry points.

Comment: radal, I tried your solution, but now the application is blocking till the Startup-EJB is started up. This is okay for avoiding failures, but from the point of the user it is bad, since no report gets back, like http 503: service unavailable, try later

Comment: @hkais - you could solve that by using a servlet filter + global flag (either static in some infinispan cache) - Startup EJB sets the flag, filter either passes request or returns 503, according to the flag. map the filter to /*.